# vector - character/integer class (under the hood)

Tags: r, vector, integer, character, numeric

Starting to learn R, and I would appreciate some help understanding how R decides the class of different vectors. I initialize `vec <- c(1:6)` and when I perform `class(vec)` I get 'integer'. Why is it not 'numeric', because I thought integers in R looked like this: `4L`
Also with `vec2 <- c(1,'a',2,TRUE)`, why is `class(vec2)` 'character'? I'm guessing R picks up on the characters and automatically assigns everything else to be characters...so then it actually looks like `c('1','a','2','TRUE')` am I correct?

Comment: If at least one of your values in the vector is character the all the vector is considered as a character.

Comment: Use a `list` if you want individual elements to be stored with different type

Comment: From `?c`: "The output type is determined from the highest type of the
     components in the hierarchy NULL < raw < logical < integer <
     double < complex < character < list < expression.".

Comment: The representation of an `integer` is generally indistinguishable from the representation of an approximated `numeric`. The `L` is used solely for *defining* an integer, not for viewing them. (Perhaps to clarify or at the risk of muddying the waters: `is.integer(4L) && is.numeric(4L)` is true, since an `integer` is really a special case of a `numeric`, even if the internal storage and precision are quite different.)

Comment: Great, thank you all! Appreciate the help :)

Comment: @r2evans, post your comment as answer ... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type the following, you can see the help page of the colon operator.

```
?`:`
```

Here is one paragraph.

> For numeric arguments, a numeric vector. This will be of type integer
>   if from is integer-valued and the result is representable in the R
>   integer type, otherwise of type "double" (aka mode "numeric").

So, in your example `c(1:6)`, since `1` for the `from` argument can be representable in R as integer, the resulting sequence becomes integer.

By the way, `c` is not needed to create a vector in this case.

For the second question, since in a vector all the elements have to be in the same type, R will automatically convert all the elements to the same. In this case, it is possible to convert everything to be character, but it is not possible to convert "a" to be numeric, so it results in a character vector.